# Failed to compile a simple c code with architecture not supported on mac os

Tags: c, macos, compiler-errors, clang

The code is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main () {
    printf("Defined\n");
}
```

And the simple code is compiled with

```
gcc test.c -o test

or 

clang test.c -o test
```

It throws ...

```
In file included from test.c:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:68:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:784:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
In file included from test.c:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from test.c:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'; did
      you mean '__int128_t'?
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did
      you mean '__int128_t'?
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
```

And more similar errors.

Of course the compiler properly works before, but after I updated mac os to 10.14.5 (18F132), it happens. Looks like there are some problems on compiler settings but I don't have any ideas where to start.

My clang version is

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: If the problem should go somewhere like clang bugzilla, please let me know.

Comment: It looks like rather you are compiling with the MacOS compiler but with the build environment set for iOS thus picking up the iOS headers rather then the native headers.  Check your environment with `printenv | grep iPhoneOS` for example to find the likely culprits.  Can you build a project within the Xcode IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @robthebloke,

I reinstalled everything related to xcode and it doesnt work. I rebooted the mac so that environmental variable are reset and it does work!

It looks like somehow I accidentally touched the environmental variables but I couldn't verify exactly which one is causing the problem.

FYI: I usually compile a bunch of c codes into several platforms: mac os, android, and ios. I guess my cross compile scripts have problem with the updated os or compiler(?).

And as @Clifford said, `printenv | grep iPhoneOS` might identify the problem.